How to perform extrinsic regression on variable-length time series
I have a signal that describes the the flow in a water pipe. Assuming that individual water consumptions have constant flow rate, each water consumption could also be described by its starting time, duration and amplitude.
Each measurement series (comprising a varying number of water consumptions) has different time length - i.e. from one hour up to forty-eight hours.
My goal is to estimate a value that depends on all water consumptions - i.e. soil moisture.
One approach are methods that perform regression directly on the time series ("Extrinsic Time Series Regression").
Would it also be possible to make a "list" of the individual water consumptions (sthg like events?) and use "classical" machine learning methods on them? How do I transform the varying number of events so that classical machine learning methods with fixed number of inputs work?

Neural nets can handle variable-length sequences, and provide a soil moisture estimate at the output. In particular, 1D convolutional nets or recurrent architectures like LSTMs.
